# Technologies list (tag autocomplete) layout misalignment in My Profile in Stack Overflow Careers

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, design

Here's a screenshot of the error shown for the list layout alignment issue. I don't know what it is called, so I did my best.

I'm using Google Chrome version 38.0.2125.104 m, telling me that I'm up-to-date.

If it's a browser issue, then I can't update it, as I don't have admin rights and had to go report this issue to the admin.

[image]

Comment: No worries, [that is the latest stable version of Chrome](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.com/2014/10/stable-channel-update_14.html). And I'm also able to reproduce this in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: No repro for same Chrome version under Windows 7. What OS?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I was able to reproduce it on OSX Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: @Steven so it might be specific to OSX if OP also got it and not Windows...

Comment: @ShadowWizard Possibly. But CSS issues like that are rarely OS dependent. [I was able to reproduce it using Chrome on Android.](http://imgur.com/0daVYfb)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I was on Windows 7 x64 Enterprise at my school's lab computer, when it happened. I can easily reproduce the results on all lab computers, since they have the same images on each machines.

Comment: Well, let's hope a dev would be able to reproduce it. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Do you know who the devs are, or where can I find a list of devs? Thanks.

Comment: The Careers team is quite big, feel free to browse [this list of completed bug reports](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed+careers) to see part of them. Don't worry, one of them will see this bug soon enough and work his/her magic. (Nick Craver and Joel are *not* part of the Careers team, by the way)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**@tom_mai78101** — Sorry about that. As we're updating the overall layouts (and moving away from declared pixel widths), some of our Javascript hadn't been fully updated yet. Sorry for the issues here.

This has been corrected and the fix has been published.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks for your time.